# Azure Backup Policy only work with two VMs

Tags: azure, azure-policy

I use Azure Backup Policy to Configure the Azure VMs with Azure Backup.

I use the Tag "backup" with the Value for the Azure Backup Policy. For Example, "default/longtimearchive/ etc."...
Now when I deploy this Policy on the Subscription, I only found 2 VMs.

But I have more than 6 VMs with this Tag.

I have checked the Follow:

Subscription = Correct

The location from The Vault and the VM is the same.

The Tag is set. I have checked it with Powershell.

I have tried to use an other Tag+Value, but it doesn't work.

Why found I only 2 of these 6 VMs?

When I used the Policy "Azure Backup should be enabled for Virtual Machines," I found all of the VMs.

Thanks a lot.

Best Regards,
Phil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few things to check:

Make sure that the VMs are within the scope of the policy. The scope of the policy can be defined by resource group, subscription, or individual VMs. If the VMs are not within the scope of the policy, they will not be included in the policy.

For VM's with unmanaged disks; If the VMs are in a "stopped" or "deallocated" state, they will not be included in the policy. Check if the ones not being backed up are unmanaged?

Check the tags on the VMs. Make sure that the tags on the VMs match the tags defined in the policy. If the tags do not match, the VMs will not be included in the policy.